# Sorting values of multiple arrays based on year and unique code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel document with a lot of data. I have four columns that I use.

1. fiscal year
2. Gain/loss on ineffective hedges
3. SIC code.
4. Sorted unique SIC code so no one appears more than once.

I have created 4 arrays and stored the values in them.

What I want to do, but have some problems with right now, is to go through each year (from 2001-2018) and calculate the average gain/loss(2) for each SIC code, for each year. I have written the following code:

[image]

```
Sub Assignment4()

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim iLastRow As Integer, iLastRow2 As Integer
Dim readStart As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim ArrayFiscalYear() As String
Dim ArrayGL() As String
Dim ArraySIC() As Variant
Dim ArraySICSorted() As Integer
ReDim ArrayFiscalYear(10000)
ReDim ArrayGL(10000)
ReDim ArraySIC(10000)
ReDim ArraySICSorted(10000)
Dim year As Integer
Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim avg As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim counter As Integer



iLastRow = Ws.Cells(Rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
count = 2
readStart = 2



Do While (count <= iLastRow)
    ArraySIC(count) = Ws.Cells(count, 10)
    count = count + 1
Loop



    
Ws.Range("J2:J" & iLastRow).AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Ws.Range("L1"), _
Unique:=True

Ws.Cells(1, 12) = "Sorted SIC"


iLastRow2 = Ws.Cells(Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print (iLastRow2)

count = 0
counter = 2

Do While (count <= iLastRow2)
    ArraySICSorted(count) = Ws.Cells(counter, 12)
    Debug.Print (ArraySICSorted(count))
    count = count + 1
    counter = counter + 1
Loop


Ws.Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete


i = 2
year = 2001
count = 0
x = 1
Do While year <= 2018
    For x = LBound(ArraySICSorted) To UBound(ArraySICSorted)
        For i = 1 To iLastRow
            If Ws.Cells(i, 3) = year Then
                ArrayFiscalYear(year) = Ws.Cells(i, 3)
                ArrayGL(year) = Ws.Cells(i, 8)
                ArraySIC(year) = Ws.Cells(i, 10)
                count = count + 1
                sum = sum + ArrayGL(year)
            End If
        Next i
        avg = sum / count
        Debug.Print (count & " --- " & ArraySICSorted(x) & " --- " & year & " --- " & x)
        sum = 0
        count = 0
        If x >= 62 Then
        year = year + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    
Loop

End Sub
```

I have attached a screen shot of my excel document

I hope someone can tell me what I do wrong so I can learn from this.

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot Table? Or is there a reason you need to create this summary using VBA?

Comment: I would prefer vba

Comment: In Excel O365, you can do this with worksheet formulas. It would also be simple to do with Power Query (or maybe a simple pivot table). If you must use VBA, I'd create a dictionary of dictionaries, from which I think it would be easier to compute your desired results.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? What results did you get versus what were you expecting?